# React Carousel not showing all images

Tags: css, reactjs

I'm trying to build a carousel but can't figure out the problem. So the first image loads fine, but every following image isn't shown. I'm guessing the component isn't rerendering, but I'm not 100%

```
const [curImage, setCurImage] = useState (0)
    const images = ['/images/slideshow/slideshow1.webp', '/images/slideshow/slideshow2.webp','/images/slideshow/slideshow3.webp', '/images/slideshow/slideshow4.webp', '/images/slideshow/slideshow5.webp', '/images/slideshow/slideshow6.webp']

    const goToNext = () => {
        setCurImage(curImage === images.length - 1 ? 0 : curImage + 1);
    }

    useEffect(() => {
        setTimeout(goToNext, 2000);
        return function() {
            clearTimeout(goToNext);
        }
    })

    return (
        <div className='Slideshow'>
            {images.map((image, key) => (
            <div 
            className={key === curImage ? 'Slideshow__Images Active':'Slideshow__Images'} 
            key={key} 
            aria-hidden={key !== curImage}
            >
                {key === curImage && (
                <img src={`${image}`} alt='Gulfport Votes Images'/>
                )}
            </div>
        ))}
        </div>
    )
```

CSS

```
.Slideshow__Images {
    opacity: 0;
    transition: 0.3s ease;
}

.Slideshow .Active {
    opacity: 1;
    transition-duration: 0.2s;
}
```

Comment: Did you check your images? Coz it works fine for me with external images. Check this [Codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/compassionate-keller-5y15d?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark)

Comment: yeah, all the images are from the public folder. The first image loads fine, but none of the rest show up